# Coordinates in Coq

Tags: coq

I apologize if this is obviously posted somewhere, but I have been trying Google search and SO search and found nothing on this yet.

**Part A.**

Is there a standard library for defining coordinates/vectors and points in R^2 and R^3 in Coq? I pretty much want to do standard stuff, like adding vectors, cross products, scaling, etc.

If not, how is this for a start:

```
Require Import Coq.Reals.Reals.

Inductive Coordinate2 : Type := Point2: R -> R -> Coordinate2.

Definition R2plus (u:Coordinate2) (v:Coordinate2) : Coordinate2 :=
match u, v with
 | (Point2 ux uy),(Point2 vx vy)=>(Point2 ((ux+vx)%R) ((uy+vy)%R))
end.  

(* etc. *)

Notation "x + y" := (R2plus x y).
```

Also, why when I run:

```
Eval compute in ((2%R) < (3%R))%R.
```

Do I get

```
= (2 < 3)%R
: Prop
```

rather than

```
 True
```

or something?

**Part B.**

Is this even a good idea? I want to build an algorithm which computes some things using real numbers, and prove the algorithm correct in Coq. Is Coq.Reals.Reals the right thing to be using, or is it really too abstract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining `Coordinate2` you could also use `(R * R)%type`, `list R`, or `t R 2`, where `t A n`, defined in `Vector`, is a list of size `n`.

You might want to give your notations a scope and a delimiting key to avoid clashes with other notations.

```
Notation "x + y" := (R2plus x y) : r2_scope.
Delimit Scope r2_scope with R2.
Eval compute in ((Point2 0 1) + (Point2 2 3))%R2.
```

`Prop`, `Set`, and `Type` are sorts, which means something of type `Prop` might be defined inductively.

For example, for the `nat`s, `le` is defined as

```
Inductive le : nat -> nat -> Prop :=
  | le_n : forall n, le n n
  | le_S : forall n m : nat, le n m -> le n (S m).
```

- `2 <= 2` is true because it's inhabited by `le_n 2`
- `2 <= 3` is true because it's inhabited by `le_S 2 2 (le_n 2)`
- `2 <= 4` is true because it's inhabited by `le_S 2 3 (le_S 2 2 (le_n 2))`
- `3 <= 2` is false because it's not inhabited

For `2 <= 3` to reduce to `True`, `le` would have to be defined like, for example,

```
Fixpoint le (n m : nat) : Prop :=
  match n with
  | 0 => True
  | S n =>
    match m with
    | 0 => False
    | S m => le n m
    end
  end.
```

Coq's definition of `Rplus` and `Rlt` are actually axioms. To check the definition of something use the `Print` command.

To answer part B, I guess it depends on how well you understand mathematical analysis and the various ways of defining the reals. If you're more familiar with numerical methods, you might want to use the rationals instead.